# Python class decorator extending class causes recursion

Tags: python, django, forms, recursion, save

I'm overwriting the save method of a `ModelForm` and I don't know why it would cause recursion:

```
@parsleyfy
class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # some other code...
        return super(AccountForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Causes this:

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Stacktrace shows this line repetitively calling itself:

```
return super(AccountForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Now, the parsley decorator is like this:

```
def parsleyfy(klass):
    class ParsleyClass(klass):
      # some code here to add more stuff to the class
    return ParsleyClass
```

As @DanielRoseman suggested that the Parsley decorator extending the `AccountForm` causes the `super(AccountForm,self)` to keep calling itself, what's the solution?

Also I cannot get my head around this why this would cause recursion.

Comment: I dont think you are supposed to return the parent save() method, just do super(AccountForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)

Comment: Are you sure that's your actual code? This is usually what happens if you've mistakenly referred to the superclass in the `super` call - eg you actually have a subclass of AccountForm, and in that overridden save method you're still calling `super(AccountForm...)`.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza you should *definitely* return a modelform super save as it is expected to return an instance

Comment: @JamesLin What does `ParsleyClass` do?  Can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: @AustinPhillips it's a decorator that extends the class being decorated and adds a few stuff to the base class.

Comment: @JamesLin: Is there a particular reason you need to override `.save()` here in the first place? (Are you putting other logic in it? The code you have right now is pointless; you could just omit the override entirely.)

Comment: @Amber there are actually other code in the save function, I omitted them out because they are not causing the problem, but I have updated the code to present the reason I need to overwrite it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you could do is just call the parent's method directly:

```
@parsleyfy
class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # some other code...
        return forms.ModelForm.save(self, *args,**kwargs)
```

This should neatly avoid the issue introduced by your class decorator. Another option would be to manually call the decorator on a differently named base class, rather than using `@` syntax:

```
class AccountFormBase(forms.ModelForm):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # some other code...
        return super(AccountFormBase, self).save(*args,**kwargs)

AccountForm = parsleyfy(AccountFormBase)
```

However, you might also want to consider using a [pre-save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save) instead, depending on what you're trying to do - it's how one normally adds functionality that should happen before the rest of the model save process in Django.

---

As for *why* this is occurring, consider what happens when the code is evaluated.

First, a class is declared. We'll refer to this original class definition as `Foo` to distinguish it from the later class definition that the decorator will create. This class has a `save` method which makes a `super(AccountForm, self).save(...)` call.

This class is then passed to the decorator, which defines a new class which we'll call `Bar`, and inherits from `Foo`. Thus, `Bar.save` is equivalent to `Foo.save` - it also calls `super(AccountForm, self).save(...)`. This second class is then returned from the decorator.

The returned class (`Bar`) is assigned to the name `AccountForm`.

So when you create an `AccountForm` object, you're creating an object of type `Bar`. When you call `.save(...)` on it, it goes and looks up `Bar.save`, which is actually `Foo.save` because it inherited from `Foo` and was never overridden.

As we noted before, `Foo.save` calls `super(AccountForm, self).save(...)`. **The problem is that because of the class decorator, `AccountForm` isn't `Foo`, it's `Bar` - and `Bar`'s parent is `Foo`.**

So when `Foo.save` looks up `AccountForm`'s parent, it gets... `Foo`. This means that when it tries to call `.save(...)` on that parent, it actually just winds up calling itself, hence the endless recursion.

Comment: What's the difference between super(AccountForm,self).save vs forms.ModelForm.save? I thought the save method is instance method and you cannot call it like that?

Comment: @JamesLin You can call it as long as you manually provide it an instance of the class as the first argument. As for what the difference is, see the second half of my answer.

Comment: @JamesLink I also added a note about [pre-save signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save), which are Django's preferred way of adding functionality that triggers immediately before a model save.

Comment: Another solution to the issue would be to give the original class a different name, then manually call the decorator to create the class you intend to use (e.g. `AccountForm`). As long as the `super` call used the name of the original class (and not the name of the decorated version), it should work as intended.

Comment: @Amber So if forms.ModelForm.save(self, *args, **kwargs) actually achieve the same thing as super(AccountForm, self).save(), why it is not generally recommended to use the first form? Looks like it will prevent a lot of situations like this.

Comment: @Blckknght Yep, that would be another way of working around the issue.

Comment: @Blckknght would you mind giving an answer with code to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @JamesLin There are other problems that can arise from calling the parent's method directly in some scenarios - especially those that involve things like calling *other* methods on the same class that may have been overridden. In single-inheritance cases, these issues don't tend to pop up, but multiple inheritance can get really tricky.

Comment: @JamesLin I've expanded my answer with an example of Blckknght's suggestion.

Comment: @JamesLin The intricacies of `super()` are far too complex to really fit in a single comment thread; I'd suggest reading through http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236275 and http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super if you really want to know more. The short story is that the concept of 'parent' becomes a lot more complex when you're using multiple inheritance (multiple superclasses, e.g. `class C(A, B):`).

Comment: @Amber Doesn't this whole thing contradicts the decorator purpose? I mean the code being decorated should not be aware of decorators.

Comment: Welcome to the joys of inheritance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24094/discussion-between-james-lin-and-amber)

Comment: (I am the author of the lib). I changed the decorator to reset the `__bases__` to `klass.__bases__`. Do you think this will cause some other problems?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done to make it work, I could either change parsleyfy class to overwrite the save method like this:

```
def parsleyfy(klass):
    class ParsleyClass(klass):
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return super(klass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    return ParsleyClass
```

or change the AccountForm's save method to be like this:

```
@parsleyfy
class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(forms.ModelForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

One thing I don't what the difference is, is `super(Class, self)` vs `super(Parent, self)` I have asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743787/python-superclass-self-method-vs-superparent-self-method)