# Python super(Class, self).method vs super(Parent, self).method

Tags: python, inheritance, parent, super

This question is derive from the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739809/django-overwriting-modelform-save-causes-recursion), let's say `class B` extends `class A`

```
class A(object):
  def do_work(self):
    print 123

class B(A):
  def do_work(self):
    super(B,self).do_work() # versus the next statement
    super(A,self).do_work() # what's the difference?
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
super(B,self).do_work()
```

will call the `do_work` function as seen by the parent class of `B` - that is, `A.do_work`.

---

```
super(A,self).do_work()
```

will call the `do_work` function as seen by the parent class of `A` - that is, `object.do_work` (which probably doesn't exist, and thus would likely raise an exception).

Comment: if doing super(A, self).do_work is not the way to go, then how do I go about solving this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739809/django-overwriting-modelform-save-causes-recursion Thanks!

Comment: @JamesLin Added an answer on that question.